# Phillips spectral theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

In Reed-Simon (see References) the following theorem due to Phillips is cited (but not proved):

> **Theorem (Phillips).** Let $X$ be a Banach space, $T \in \mathcal L(X)$. Then $\sigma(T) = \sigma(T')$ and $R_\lambda(T') = R_\lambda(T)'$. If $\mathcal H$ is in a Hilbert space, then $\sigma(T^*) = \{ \lambda : \bar\lambda \in \sigma(T) \}$ and $R_\lambda(T^*) = R_\lambda(T)^*$.

Now, the Hilbert space part is quite easy (is a standard result in many books) while the Banach space one looks more difficult. Considering that $\rho(T) = \{ \lambda : T_\lambda := T - \lambda I \, \mbox{is an isomorphism} \}$ and $\sigma(T) := \mathbb C \setminus \rho(T)$, the first claim seems true if was true that

> **Claim (?).** $T$ isomorphism $\implies T'$ isomorphism.

I don't think this statement holds (maybe I'm wrong, but it doesn't sound familiar). Indeed, it is true that

> **Proposition.** $T$ isometric isomorphism $\iff T'$ isometric isomorphism.

The proof of this proposition is not completely trivial (although is not too hard) and can be found, for example, in Costara-Popa. The property "$T$ isometry" is essential to get $T'$ isometry and hence injective, so it can't be weakened keeping the same argument for the remainder. On the other hand, from definition of $T'$, I don't see other ways to go.

Does anyone know the proof of the Phillips theorem or can provide a reference? And can anyone prove or disprove the claim?

**Notation.** $T'$ is the dual operator of $T$ (in the sense of Banach spaces), $T^*$ is the adjoint of $T$ (in the sense of Hilbert spaces), $\sigma(T)$ spectrum of $T$, $\rho(T)$ is the resolvent set and $R_\lambda(T)$ is the resolvent of $T$.

**References** Reed-Simon, *Methods of modern mathematical physics, Functional analysis*, Thm VI.7; Costara-Popa, *Exercises in Functional Analysis*, Chp. 2, Ex. 28.

Comment: If $T$ is an isomorphism, $$\operatorname{id}_{X'} = (\operatorname{id}_X)' =(T^{-1}\circ T)' = T' \circ (T^{-1})'.$$ Similar for $(T\circ T^{-1})'$. The claim follows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Proving the claim is completely straightforward. If $T$ is an isomorphism, then $\operatorname{id}_X = T^{-1}\circ T = T\circ T^{-1}$, and hence

$$\operatorname{id}_{X'} = (\operatorname{id}_X)' = (T^{-1}\circ T)' = T'\circ (T^{-1})' = (T\circ T^{-1})' = (T^{-1})'\circ T',$$

thus $T'$ is an isomorphism with inverse $(T^{-1})'$.

That shows $\rho(T) \subset \rho(T')$, and $R_\lambda(T') = R_\lambda(T)'$ for $\lambda \in \rho(T)$ follows by

$$\operatorname{id}_{X'} = (R_\lambda(T)\circ(T-\lambda I))' = (T-\lambda I)'\circ R_\lambda(T)' = (T' - \lambda I')\circ R_\lambda(T)'$$

and the composition in the other direction.

We also have the converse, $T' \text{ isomorphism} \Rightarrow T \text{ isomorphism}$: By the above, $T''$ is an isomorphism, hence $T$ is injective and has closed range. Since $T'$ is injective, $T$ has dense range, hence $T$ is also surjective, hence an isomorphism.

The inclusion $\rho(T') \subset \rho(T)$ follows by the converse of the claim  proved above.

Comment: Another question: if we identify $\mathcal H$ and $\mathcal H'$ via Riesz theorem then $T'$ and $T^*$ coincide. How is this fact related to Phillips theorem?

Comment: The identification of $\mathcal{H}'$ and $\mathcal{H}$ is antilinear, and that gives the conjugation of the spectrum. Bearing that in mind, the Hilbert space case is a special case of Phillips' theorem.